# Extract data with querySelectorAll from the page in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs

CasperJS script

```
listItems = this.evaluate(function () {
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li');
    return [].map.call(nodes, function(node) {
        return node;
    });
});

var tr_data = listItems.map(function(str) {
    var elements = str;
    // var data = {
    //     ip        : ????
    // };
    return elements;
});
```

Page Markup

```
<ul>
    <li> // Multiple Li
        <div class=“image”>
            <div class=“thumb”>
                <p>
                    <img src=“SOURCE” > // Retrieve SOURCE

            <div class=“text”>
                <p>TEXT </p> // Retrieve TEXT
```

I'm trying to retrieve **Source** and **Text**. Please advice where I can learn how to go about retrieving SOURCE & TEXT in bold.

Comment: What does "retrieving contents" mean?  What are you trying to accomplish and can you please change the title of your question to represent the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS only supports passing primitive objects in to or out of the page context ([`page.evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html)). DOM nodes are complex objects which cannot be passed. CasperJS has the exact same limitation.

You can create a primitive object in the page context and pass it out:

```
casper.then(function(){
    var listItems = this.evaluate(function () {
        var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li');
        return [].map.call(nodes, function(node) {
            return {
                source: node.querySelector(".thumb img").src,
                text: node.querySelector("div.text p").textContent
            };
        });
    });
    this.echo(JSON.stringify(listItems, undefined, 4)); // pretty print
});
```